# NextJS Build Url Path with ENV variables

Tags: next.js, next.js13

My project uses NextJS 13.1.6

I'm having trouble building a url through string concatenation using environment variables.

```
env.local:
 WEBSITE_URL: 'https://somewebsite.com/api/input';
 SECRET_KEY: '1234abcd';

src/pages/api/api-requests.js
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.WEBSITE_URL}?secret=${process.env.SECRET_KEY}`)

This url produces this output:
 "'https://www.somewebsite.com/api/input';?secret='1234abcd';'"
```

As you can see there are odd characters in that url string - semi-colons ; and quotes ''

No idea what I'm doing wrong here...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you .env file look like this

```
WEBSITE_URL = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/api/input';
```

remove `;` and `''` as [Scottish Smile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6611979/scottish-smile) commented. Because in `.env`file all variables are read as strings, so you don't need to specify

```
WEBSITE_URL = https://www.somewebsite.com/api/input
```

Comment: Thank You! I removed the semi-colon and the quotes ' ' and it worked :)